# Multiple OS on one flash drive

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, google-chrome, live-usb, usb-drive

I currently have an Ubuntu 12.04 copy on my flash drive, but I'm wondering if I can also have another OS on the same flash drive as well. If I put another OS on the drive, how will it distinguish between which one I would like to boot upon start up? Will this force me to delete the one in return for the other? Will a boot-loader activate when the other OS is detected? Also, will this cause problems considering the fact that 2 OSs will be on a single, non-partitioned space, albeit a flash drive, but still.

In case you were wondering, or that it matters at all. I will be putting Chrome OS, gotten [here](http://getchrome.eu/download.php), on with Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I hope you realize that's not Chrome OS, rather a spin of openSUSE

Answer (score 1):

> There is  a tool for creating what is basically a GRUB multi-OS
>   bootloader on your USB drive. All you have to do is grab an ISO file
>   of the system you're adding to your drive, then drop the whole ISO
>   file onto the drive (occasionally with special instructions). There's
>   all the usual Linux cohorts—Ubuntu, Fedora, openSUSE, etc.—but also
>   some great rescue tools and utilities, like the GParted partition
>   disc, Ophcrack password reset, and virus scanners. You could even load
>   a Windows 7 installation DVD onto your thumb drive, if you had the
>   room.<sup>**1**</sup>

Unfortunately, "MultiBootISOs is a free download for Windows"<sup>**1**</sup> only.  To get it, [see this site](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/).

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source: ["MultiBootISOs Boots Multiple Operating Systems from a USB Drive" on lifehacker.com](http://lifehacker.com/5584856/multibootisos-boots-multiple-live-operating-systems-from-a-usb-drive)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be theoretically possible.  So I am going to try it just to verify.

Based on answers to other questions here regarding installing OS on flash drive at all, you can just select the flash drive as part of a normal install process.

If you want to dual boot the flash drive, you will need more than one partition by necessity.  Something on the order of two roots, probably two home partitions.  I read elsewhere no swap, swap a bad idea on a flash drive.

When you get to the window of install that asks whether to install alongside or delete, you pick something else.  You probably want to sort out your partitions before you get to this point with GParted, set up a partition of unallocated free space after your original OS partition.